# WP7 file prepackaging / download OTA into isostore

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, pre-packaged

I'm making a windows phone 7 app that makes use of xml based data. I understand that I can prepackage xml files with the app (as part of the application content) and deploy them along with the XAP.

In future if I have to update the XML's on account of updated / changed data, what are the options I have?

Can I build in a method to have the user download the file? Will it overwrite the existing file?

If not, what are the other options I have if I choose to let the user download an updated XML file alone instead of asking the user to update the entire application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, and this was my solution:

- Bundle the XML files with the app as Content (so it got into the .xap file)
- Everytime I run the app, I do two things:

  - Check if a XML files are on IsolatedStorage; if they are not (first run), copy them from the app data source folder to IsolateStorage
  - Check if the files that are now in the IsolatedStorage need to be updated; if so, download the new versions and update the IsolatedStorage.
- Only use the XML files that are on IsolatedStorage